# How to list the available soft-link directories in a server linked with NFS mount

Tags: linux, symlink, nfs

We have many directories on a server. These directories were created as soft-link and linked it with some NFS share. I would like to list the soft link directories which linked with NFS shares.

we used the commands below to create soft-link directory and link with NFS.

```
client 1 # ln -s /net/rchserver01/data/share2/ /tmp/
client 1 # ln -s /net/rchserver01/data/share1/ /var/
client 1 # ll /tmp/
lrwxrwxrwx 1 root     root  27 Sep 13 11:38 share2 -> /net/rchserver01/data/share2/
client 1 # ll /var/
lrwxrwxrwx 1 root     root  27 Sep 13 11:38 share2 -> /net/rchserver01/data/share1/
```

Comment: Are all the NFS shares under /net? Just wondering what assumptions we can make.

Comment: Yes, using mount command I can see the NFS servers. But I need to know the softlink directories where these NFS mounted.

Answer (score 2):

Given the sample input:

```
find /tmp -lname '/net/*'
```

More generally, tell `find` to explore every local filesystem, but to stay on each filesystem:

```
find $(lsblk --list --noheadings --output MOUNTPOINT | grep /) -xdev -lname '/net/*'
```

Even more generally, ask `find` to search the local filesystems, as above, but build up a list of possible NFS targets:

```
readarray -t nfsmounts < <(awk '$3 ~ /^nfs/ { print $2 }' < /proc/mounts)
excludes=()
excludes+=("(")
excludes+=(" -lname ${nfsmounts[0]}")
for((i=1;i < ${#nfsmounts[@]}; i++))
do
  excludes+=( " -o -lname '${nfsmounts[i]}/*'")
done
excludes+=(")")
find $(lsblk --list --noheadings --output MOUNTPOINT | grep /) -xdev ${excludes[@]}
```

Another alternative for the starting list of filesystems: parse /proc/filesystems for filesystem types that are *not* `nodev`:

```
find $( for type in $(awk '$1 != "nodev"' /proc/filesystems); do mount -l -t "$type" | awk '{print $3}'; done ) \
  -xdev -lname '/net/*'
```

Comment: Thanks a lot !! It worked. But I need to run find command for all filesystems to find the softlink dirs. Since I would not know where my softlink dir exists.

Comment: Run the `find` with all your local filesystems, and add `-xdev`; looking to see if we have a good "local filesystems" answer here... stole [one of my own](https://unix.stackexchange.com/a/421669/117549)

Comment: @JeffSchaller Maybe `find / -type nfs -prune -lname '/net/*'` This should  not descend into any NFS file systems.

Comment: Aye, @Doug, but there's also tmpfs and sysfs and devpts and autofs and ...

Comment: Maybe something more along the lines of `mount -l -t (each of -- awk '$1 != "nodev"' /proc/filesystems)`

Comment: @Doug, Command is giving error. /root # find / -type nfs -prune -lname '/net/*'
find: Arguments to -type should contain only one letter

Comment: @JeffSchaller, Is that the right command - mount -l -t (each of -- awk '$1 != "nodev"' /proc/filesystems)

Comment: No, @Pandu, sorry for the confusion. I was trying to find a better way to list the local filesystems, and was brainstorming.

Comment: @JeffSchaller. It worked. Thank you, everyone !!